# Camera Permission on Webview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this AR simple application hosted on [1]: https://github.com/haybee1001/MyARExperiencee6tby it when i open the link on my phone browser it calls/ request for camera permission and opens camera (works perfectly).

However, i decided to wrap up this link in a Xamarin WebView. However, it complains about permission. I have tried some solutions to this online but am still stocked.

Please How can i achieve/call camera permission on WebView ? Can someone show me a working solution with my app link.

Comment: https://haybee1001.github.io/MyARExperiencee6tby/ Actual app Link

Answer (score 0):

You could request `Camera` permission on runtime when entering the webview page in Xamarin Forms.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webView.Source = "your webview";
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    RunTimePermission();
}

public async void RunTimePermission()
{
    var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

    status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);

    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {

        status = await Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Camera);
    }

}
```

Here using the **[Permissions Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)** to request permission.

The **Utils.cs** code as follows:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckPermissions(Permission permission)
    {
        var permissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
        bool request = false;
        if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {

                var title = $"{permission} Permission";
                var question = $"To use this plugin the {permission} permission is required. Please go into Settings and turn on {permission} for the app.";
                var positive = "Settings";
                var negative = "Maybe Later";
                var task = Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(title, question, positive, negative);
                if (task == null)
                    return permissionStatus;

                var result = await task;
                if (result)
                {
                    CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
                }

                return permissionStatus;
            }

            request = true;

        }

        if (request || permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var newStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permission);

            if (!newStatus.ContainsKey(permission))
            {
                return permissionStatus;
            }

            permissionStatus = newStatus[permission];

            if (newStatus[permission] != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                permissionStatus = newStatus[permission];
                var title = $"{permission} Permission";
                var question = $"To use the plugin the {permission} permission is required.";
                var positive = "Settings";
                var negative = "Maybe Later";
                var task = Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(title, question, positive, negative);
                if (task == null)
                    return permissionStatus;

                var result = await task;
                if (result)
                {
                    CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
                }
                return permissionStatus;
            }
        }

        return permissionStatus;
    }
}
```

In **MainActivity.cs**, add the code in `OnCreate` method.

```
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

`OnRequestPermissionsResult` method is needed in **MainActivity.cs**.

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, 
[GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Not forget to add the user permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```